# How do I hard code a version number into a cmake cpack with dynamic version number

Tags: git, cmake, packaging

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that specifies the project without a hard coded version number:

```
project (project_name C CXX)
```

Then a little further down [includes a script](https://github.com/alerque/xiphos/blob/cmake-auto-version/cmake/modules/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake) and uses a function to figure out the version number based on `git describe`:

```
include(GetGitRevisionDescription)
git_describe(GIT_VERSION --tags)
string(REGEX REPLACE "-([0-9]*).*" ".\\1" VERSION "${GIT_VERSION}")
```

The result is lovely for building the project from the git repository using `cmake`, tagged commits have the right version, HEAD builds after that have an extra field (tweak version) with a counter for commits since the last tag.

The trouble is when using CPack to bundle a source tarball, the `CMakeLists.txt` in the tarball no longer has a way to determine it's own version (to `.git` directory and all that).

How do I change the generated `CMakeLists.txt` in the tarball to have a hard coded version number?